# Sabre HotelRateDescription soap call failing, don't understand error message or whats wrong?

Tags: sabre

I am following a sample SOAP request outlined in the [docs here](http://webservices.sabre.com/drc/servicedoc/HotelRateDescriptionLLSRQ_v2.3.0_Sample_Payloads.xml). (The second one: "Perform a stateless hotel rate description")

I don't understand what I am doing wrong? My SOAP body looks the same format to the sample to me and I can't get much info from the error message?

My Soap body looks like this:

```
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <HotelRateDescriptionRQ Version="2.3.0" xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10">
        <AvailRequestSegment>
            <GuestCounts Count="1"></GuestCounts>
            <HotelSearchCriteria>
                <Criterion>
                    <HotelRef HotelCode="0014695"></HotelRef>
                </Criterion>
            </HotelSearchCriteria>
            <RatePlanCandidates>
                <RatePlanCandidate CurrencyCode="GBP" DCA_ProductCode="SUPHFH"></RatePlanCandidate>
            </RatePlanCandidates>
            <TimeSpan End="01-13" Start="01-12"></TimeSpan>
        </AvailRequestSegment>
    </HotelRateDescriptionRQ>
</s:Body>
```

The response body is this:

```
<soap-env:Body>
    <HotelRateDescriptionRS xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:stl="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01" Version="2.3.0">
        <stl:ApplicationResults status="NotProcessed">
            <stl:Error type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2017-01-04T05:43:02-06:00">
                <stl:SystemSpecificResults>
                    <stl:Message code="0">VERIFY FORMAT</stl:Message>
                    <stl:ShortText>ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE</stl:ShortText>
                </stl:SystemSpecificResults>
            </stl:Error>
        </stl:ApplicationResults>
    </HotelRateDescriptionRS>
</soap-env:Body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HotelRateDescriptionLLSRQ is a low level service which means that behind the scenes it runs a native Sabre command. When the service says VERIFY FORMAT it doesn't mean the XML format, but the Sabre format (host command) that is being run.

In this particular scenario, it seems to be related to the independent HRD functionality not being enabled for you. If you want to have this enabled, you'll need to reach out to your Sabre account representative.

Else, you'll need to make a simple HRD request specifying the line number of the rate you want to display from a previous HotelPropertyDescriptionLLSRQ call.

This is how it'd look:

```
<AvailRequestSegment>
    <RatePlanCandidates>
        <RatePlanCandidate RPH="3" />
    </RatePlanCandidates>
</AvailRequestSegment>
```

Hope you find this useful!

Bruno.

Comment: Okay cool that makes sense Bruno thanks. So I should be able to use this independent HRD functionality if my account rep just turns it on for us? Others are using it?

Comment: I don't think it is very common but I guess it makes sense to use it if you always work with the same hotels and want to save a few calls.
The most common flow is OTA_HotelAvailLLSRQ / HotelPropertyDescriptionLLSRQ / HotelRateDescriptionLLSRQ. 

It is further described here: https://developer.sabre.com/docs/workflows/book_hotel_reservation

Comment: Yup makes sense - our use case is in fact that we do an OTA_HotelAvailLLSRQ, then we might do a HotelPropertyDescriptionLLSRQ on hotel 1 that was returned, then a HotelPropertyDescriptionLLSRQ on hotel 2 that was returned, THEN want to go back and do a HotelRateDescriptionLLSRQ on hotel 1 without another HotelPropertyDescriptionLLSRQ call.

Comment: the reason it's "out of order" is that the hotels returned from OTA_HotelAvailLLSRQ are displayed in a list back to the customer, and it's up to them what order they "click the buttons" that would initiate the subsequent calls. Does that make sense? Only possible with this stateless HOD call I'm guessing?

Comment: hey @Bruno - can you comment on this? Any other way you see of doing what we need "out of order HOD/HRD calls" without the IHRD?

Comment: There could be several solutions for that problem. 

You could remove the possibility for the customer to display several hotels at once, and making them to select another hotel before they could see the rates. 

Or you could make a new HotelPropertyDescriptionLLSRQ call transparent to the customer when they select a rate from another hotel. 

Alternatively, you could use multiple parallel threads for different hotels, although this could be demanding for your pool of sessions.

You could always request the i-HRD to your account manager. 

Let me know how it goes! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

hi i am working with sabre and create one large application for hotels booking using sabre. your sample request for "HotelRateDescriptionRQ" is look like as following. I am not share response over here but i am sure this request is work for you.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
-<HotelRateDescriptionRQ Version="2.3.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 -<AvailRequestSegment xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10">
  -<RatePlanCandidates>
      <RatePlanCandidate RPH="001"/>
    </RatePlanCandidates>
   </AvailRequestSegment>
 </HotelRateDescriptionRQ>
```

and sample response is look like as following

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
-<HotelRateDescriptionRS Version="2.3.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 -<ApplicationResults xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01" status="Complete">   
     <Success timeStamp="2017-03-10T11:34:37+05:30"/>    
  </ApplicationResults>
 -<RoomStay xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10">...
```

you can also used properties description request which provide all room rate details.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
-<HotelPropertyDescriptionRQ Version="2.3.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    -<AvailRequestSegment xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10">
        <GuestCounts Count="1"/>
        -<HotelSearchCriteria>
        -<Criterion>        
            <HotelRef HotelCode="0015309"/>
        </Criterion>
        </HotelSearchCriteria>
        -<RatePlanCandidates>
            <ContractNegotiatedRateCode>WKH</ContractNegotiatedRateCode>
            <RateRange CurrencyCode="USD"/>
        </RatePlanCandidates>
        <TimeSpan Start="03-23" End="03-24"/>
    </AvailRequestSegment>
</HotelPropertyDescriptionRQ>
```